# Why does hook_menu_link not work?

Tags: 7, theming

[theme_menu_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7.x) allegedly "Returns HTML for a menu link and submenu."

In attempting to use this 'hook' I added code to my template.php as such:

```
function themename_menu_link(array $vars) {
  dpm($vars);
}
```

It didn't work.  Nothing appears.

I confirmed that the template.php code is executing and cleared caches several times.

Every other hook_ or theme_ function I've tested runs without issue, however this one does not.

I've also tested the alternative method, themename_menu_link__your_menu_name with no success.  The code seems to be ignored.

Comment: Can you confirm it is being hit with either an exit or xdebug breakpoint? Just to clarify, you aren't literally calling it themename_menu_link are you?

Comment: What (base) theme are you using? Some don't use `menu_tree_output`, and as such don't invoke that theme function

Comment: @Kevin no, the theme is foo, and the function is foo_menu_link :)  I think Clive might have hit the nail though.  I'll check back in a few.

Comment: I think you're right, @Clive.  I'll post back in a few.

Comment: @Clive you are correct, the theme_menu_link does not fire on all default menus implemented in a theme.
Changing over to block menus fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try print_r instead of dpm --

```
function theme_menu_link(array $variables) {
  return print_r($variables['element']);
}
```

or use [hook_menu_link_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/7.x) --

```
hook_menu_link_alter($variables){
  var_dump($variables);
}
```

Comment: The print_r you suggest would require the boolean set to true to actually work; but thank you all the same.